# DataAnnotations Support in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-annotations

I would like to use data annotations on my classes and entities in a Windows Forms application (WinForms). I use windows DataGridViews and Infragistics UltraGrids. I have previously successfully used the `[DisplayName("Name to Display")]` attribute to set the column header text on a DataGridView/UltraGrid.

This is very beneficial, because I may have several grids displaying this class, and instead of configuring each grid to display the appropriate header text, I can simply set one data annotation.

I'd like to make use of the following Data Annotations as well:

- Display
- [Display(AutoGenerateField=false)]

  - Do not display this column
- [Display(Order=N)]

  - Display this column as the nth column in the grid
- DisplayColumn
- [DisplayColumn("ColumnName")]

  - If this object is a property of another object, display this column value instead of the object type
- Display Format
- [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:formatstring}")]

  - Format the data using the specified format string
- DataType
- [DataType(DataType.Currency)]

  - Display the data as a currency in the default local currency format

**Example**

Given the following annotated data classes:

```
public class Item
{
    //Specifies that the column should not be displayed
    [Display(AutoGenerateField = false)] 
    public int ItemID { get; set; }

    //Specifies that the column should be the 1st column in the datagridview
    [Display(Order = 1)]
    public int Name { get; set; }

    //Specifies that the column should be the 3rd column in the datagridview
    //Specifies that the column header text should display "Cost" instead of "Price"
    [Display(Order = 3, Name="Cost")]
    //Specifies that the column should be rendered using the default local currency format string
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public int Price { get; set; }

    //Specifies that the column should be the 4th column in the datagridview  
    [Display(Order = 4)]
    //specifies that the column should be rendered using the datetime format string "M/d/yy h:mm tt"
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:M/d/yy h:mm tt")]
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }

    //Specifies that the column should be the 2nd column in the datagridview
    [Display(Order = 2)]
    public ItemCategory Category { get; set; }
}
//Specifies that the Name column should be displayed, if referenced in a containing object
[DisplayColumn("Name")] 
public class ItemCategory
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I would like the DataGridView to render like this:

```
+-------+---------------+--------+-----------------+
|  Name |    Category   |  Cost  |  ExpirationDate |
+-------+---------------+--------+-----------------+
| Item1 | Category1Name | $30.45 | 7/23/17 5:22 PM |
+-------+---------------+--------+-----------------+
| Item2 | Category1Name | $45.05 | 8/24/17 6:22 PM |
+-------+---------------+--------+-----------------+
| Item3 | Category2Name | $35.50 | 9/25/17 7:22 PM |
+-------+---------------+--------+-----------------+
```

However in practice with DataGridViews in .Net 4.5.2 WinForms, the datagrid is actually displayed as follows:

```
+----+-------+-------+----------------+--------------------+
| ID |  Name | Price | ExpirationDate |      Category      |
+----+-------+-------+----------------+--------------------+
| 1  | Item1 | 30.45 | 7/23/17        | Namespace.Category |
+----+-------+-------+----------------+--------------------+
| 2  | Item2 | 45.05 | 8/24/17        | Namespace.Category |
+----+-------+-------+----------------+--------------------+
| 3  | Item3 | 35.50 | 9/25/17        | Namespace.Category |
+----+-------+-------+----------------+--------------------+
```

**Documentation**

The documentation declares that it is supported in ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC.

[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx)

> The System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace provides attribute classes that are used to define metadata for ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET data controls.

**Questions**
It seems that these classes have not been adopted/supported in the windows forms environment. Is this true?

Is there a simple way to implement support for the data annotations in WinForms?

Is there a simple way to annotate the classes/entities that can be used to format the display of a DataGridView and/or UltraGrid?

Comment: [DataAnnotations Validation attributes for Windows Forms](http://www.reza-aghaei.com/dataannotations-validation-attributes-in-windows-forms/)

Comment: [DisplayName, Description and Format attributes for Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50911813/3110834)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither Infragistics UltraGrid nor the Windows DataGridView support data annotations in this manner.  DevExpress as of 15.1 has some limited WinForms data annotation support within its Data Layout Control https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/thinking/archive/2015/06/08/winforms-data-layout-control-data-annotation-attributes.aspx.

I found this link where someone is asking similar questions about how to suppress columns within Infragistics Grid by looking at metadata: http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/91864.aspx

Answer (score 10):

### DataAnnotations attributes for DataGridView in Windows Forms

> There is no built-in support for Data Annotation in Windows Forms, but
> knowing how the attributes work and how windows forms work, we can
> use them in windows forms.

Here in this post, I'll show an extension method for `DataGridView` which binds an `IList<T>` to `DataGridView` and auto-generate columns based on the data annotations attributes, so you can get the following `DataGridView`, by calling `dataGridView1.Bind(list);`:

Look at the following items which are coming from data annotations attributes:

- **Column visibility**: Id column is invisible
- **Column header texts**: They are custom texts different from property names
- **Order of columns**: The order of columns is custom, different from property orders
- **Tooltip**: We have shown custom tooltip for columns.
- **Format of data**: We have used custom format for date.

And many more things still you can have using attributes.

[image]

While the model is like this:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

[TypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(MetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider))]
public class Person
{
    [Display(Name = "Id")]
    [Browsable(false)]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name", Description = "First name.", Order = 1)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name", Description = "Last name", Order = 2)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Birth Date", Description = "Date of birth.", Order = 4)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd")]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Homepage", Description = "Url of homepage.", Order = 5)]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Member", Description = "Is member?", Order = 3)]
    public bool IsMember { get; set; }
}
```

**Bind<T> Extension Method**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public static class DataGridViewExtensions
{
    public static void Bind<T>(this DataGridView grid, IList<T> data,
        bool autoGenerateColumns = true)
    {
        if (autoGenerateColumns)
        {
            var properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
            var metedata = properties.Cast<PropertyDescriptor>().Select(p => new
            {
                Name = p.Name,
                HeaderText = p.Attributes.OfType<DisplayAttribute>()
                    .FirstOrDefault()?.Name ?? p.DisplayName,
                ToolTipText = p.Attributes.OfType<DisplayAttribute>()
                    .FirstOrDefault()?.GetDescription() ?? p.Description,
                Order = p.Attributes.OfType<DisplayAttribute>()
                    .FirstOrDefault()?.GetOrder() ?? int.MaxValue,
                Visible = p.IsBrowsable,
                ReadOnly = p.IsReadOnly,
                Format = p.Attributes.OfType<DisplayFormatAttribute>()
                    .FirstOrDefault()?.DataFormatString,
                Type = p.PropertyType
            });
            var columns = metedata.OrderBy(m => m.Order).Select(m =>
            {
                DataGridViewColumn c;
                if (m.Type == typeof(bool)) {
                    c = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn(false); }
                else if (m.Type == typeof(bool?)) {
                    c = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn(true); }
                else { c = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn(); }
                c.DataPropertyName = m.Name;
                c.Name = m.Name;
                c.HeaderText = m.HeaderText;
                c.ToolTipText = m.ToolTipText;
                c.DefaultCellStyle.Format = m.Format;
                c.ReadOnly = m.ReadOnly;
                c.Visible = m.Visible;
                return c;
            });
            grid.Columns.Clear();
            grid.Columns.AddRange(columns.ToArray());
        }
        grid.DataSource = data;
    }
}
```

### DataAnnotations Validation attributes for Windows Forms

Also for supporting data annotations validations you can implement `IDataErrorInfo` interface using `Validator` class, the same way that I've done it in [DataAnnotations Validation attributes for Windows Forms](http://www.reza-aghaei.com/dataannotations-validation-attributes-in-windows-forms/).

**Note**

To enhance the answer, you may want to creating a type descriptor which cares about metadata attributes and then decorate the models with that type descriptor. You can start by using the code of [`AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptor`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptor.cs), [`MetadataPropertyDescriptorWrapper`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/MetadataPropertyDescriptorWrapper.cs), [`AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider.cs).

Also you can create a Metadata class and apply the effect of some attributes like `Url` or `DataType` on the metadata. Looking into this post will give you some idea: [Combining multiple Attributes to a single Attribute - Merge Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38503146/3110834).

Comment: Thanks for your link.  I was able to get an error message in _context.Errors but unable to get errors on individual properties or to get the text box to turn red.   Can you help, Reza?

Comment: @Missy, take a look at my [blog post](http://www.reza-aghaei.com/dataannotations-validation-attributes-in-windows-forms/), see the pictures, also download the code example which I've shared on GitHub. You need to use ErrorProvider and BindingSource and setup data-binding.

Comment: Thanks, Reza, I did and your code works beautifully but I can't make mine work.  I'm using EF Core and the validation is producing an error message but it's not highlighting the fields.  I must be missing a setting.