# How to bind DataGridView to specific properties?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Say if this is my Data class

```cs
class Data
{
    public int A { set; get;}
    public long B { set; get;}
    public string C { set; get;}
}
```

Now I have a collection of `Data` as data source and I want the `DataGridView` to bind to it.

But I only want to display `A` and `C` in the view. What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Suggested reading: [BrowsableAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute?view=net-7.0)

Comment: In addition to all common solution, you may be interested in using [DataAnnotations attributes for DataGridView in Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59885956/3110834).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the columns you want to the grid in the designer. Set the `DataPropertyName` of each column to the name of the data source property/column that you want to bind to. Before binding the data in code, set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `false`, so that the grid doesn't create any extra columns.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is **how to bind DataGridView to specific properties** . You mention that you have a collection of `Data` but don't say whether it's observable (for example `BindingList<Data>`). You end your post with ***what's the easiest way to do this?*** While that's a matter of opinion, one way that I personally find very easy is to *allow* `AutoGenerateColumns` and do column formatting on a bindable source in the `OnLoad` override of the form.

---

**Example**

[image: screenshot]

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();
    internal BindingList<Data> Rows { get; } = new BindingList<Data>();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        dataGridView.DataSource = Rows;
        dataGridView.CellEndEdit += (sender, e) => dataGridView.Refresh();

        #region F O R M A T    C O L U M N S
        Rows.Add(new Data()); // <= Auto-generate columns
        dataGridView.Columns["A"].Width = 50;
        dataGridView.Columns["A"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        dataGridView.Columns["A"].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        dataGridView.Columns["C"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        dataGridView.Columns["C"].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        Rows.Clear();
        #endregion F O R M A T    C O L U M N S

        // Add a few items
        Rows.Add(new Data { A = 1, B = 1000L });
        Rows.Add(new Data { A = 2, B = 2000L });
        Rows.Add(new Data { A = 3, B = 3000L });
    }
}
```

The `Data` class defines whether the column is shown and editable using visibility and attributes.

```
class Data
{
    // A visible, editable cell.
    public int A { get; set; }

    // Non-visible because property is declared as internal.
    internal long B { get; set; }

    // Visible, read-only cell that dynamically responds
    // when cell 'A" is edited due to Refresh() 
    public string C => $"A={A} B={B}";

    // Non-visible because of attribute.
    [Browsable(false)]
    public string? D { get; set; } = "Not visible";        
}
```

---

Another alternative, provided the column exists in the first place, is that it can be shown-hidden. For example:  `dataGridView.Columns["C"].Visible = false`.